# Issue with programmatically added buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, lifecycle

I have a cell in the `UITableView`. The cell has a `UITableViewCell` class. In this class I programmatically add few buttons.

Note: the cell is located in the very end of the table view.

Issue:
If I'm using simulator iphone 5 > the buttons will be shown.
But if I'm using simulator iphone 6+ > the buttons will NOT be shown.

Note: when i'm opening it on iphone 5 I need to scroll to see that particular cell. on iphone 6+ i don't need to scroll there, the cell is visible right away.

So I think the issue is somewhere here. May be with the place where I do my 'buttons adding'.

Where should I call the method that sets up the buttons? 
Or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Add button Programmatically under the method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" and add in cell

Comment: You need to show some code. Where do you add it? Do you clean the cell (especially since they are reused)?

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** If you have different cell types in your table view, you should make sure they have different identifiers.

**Explanation:**

Table cells are re-used within the `UITableView` and when the table is first being displayed it won't have any re-usable cells yet. It gets the cells to display by calling on its data source through the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

The thing providing the cells will first ask the table view if it has any re-usable cells (of a particular type), before creating a new one. The way it determines the particular type is from the `reuseIdentifier` in the table cell.

So, if you have two different classes of table cell, but they share the same `reuseIdentifier` you will sometimes get one class and sometimes the other - if you get the one without buttons when you're expecting the buttons then this will be a problem!

The answer is to make sure your different cell types have a unique `reuseIdentifier`.